# GetRuntimeInterfaceMap Returns Unexpected Mapped Method

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, system.reflection

I am running into a problem with [`GetRuntimeInterfaceMap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.runtimereflectionextensions.getruntimeinterfacemap(v=vs.110).aspx) ([`GetInterfaceMap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfacemap(v=vs.110).aspx) also exhibits the same behavior) and I am hoping to have someone shed some light on what I am doing wrong, and how I can possibly address it.  Here is a simple xUnit test along with corresponding code that demonstrates the issue:

(I also [have it hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/Mike-EEE/Stash/tree/master/Reflection.InterfaceMaps) if you would like to run it locally in VS2015+).

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xunit;

namespace Reflection.InterfaceMaps
{
    public class BasicTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void VerifyMappings()
        {
            var expected = typeof(Expected).GetTypeInfo().GetRuntimeInterfaceMap( typeof(ICommand) );
            Assert.Equal( "System.Windows.Input.ICommand.Execute", expected.TargetMethods.Last().Name );

            var unexpected = typeof(Unexpected).GetTypeInfo().GetRuntimeInterfaceMap( typeof(ICommand) );
            Assert.Equal( "System.Windows.Input.ICommand.Execute", unexpected.TargetMethods.Last().Name ); // Fails with "Execute"
        }
    }

    interface ICommand<in T> : ICommand
    {
        void Execute( T parameter );
    }

    abstract class CommandBase<T> : ICommand<T>
    {
        bool ICommand.CanExecute( object parameter ) => false;
        void ICommand.Execute( object parameter ) {}
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public abstract void Execute( T parameter );
    }

    class Expected : CommandBase<object>
    {
        public override void Execute( object parameter ) {}
    }

    interface IUnexpected : ICommand<object> {}
    class Unexpected : CommandBase<object>, IUnexpected
    {
        public override void Execute( object parameter ) {}
    }
```

As you can see, the `Expected` type returns the expected mapping to the desired explicitly defined method of `System.Windows.Input.ICommand.Execute`. However, the `Unexpected` type does not.  `Unexpected` also implements `IUnexpected` which implements `ICommand<>` which in turn implements `ICommand`, the ultimate interface I am interested in.

I would expect that the requested interface mapping for `ICommand` would return the explicit method mapped as found in the expected map, but alas it does not.

Is there another consideration here that I should explore?  Or is this perhaps a bug? (Never know :) ).

Comment: Pretty standard C# syntax trap.  Interfaces never implement anything, they only demand that a class that "derives" from it implements the interface.  And if you "derive" an interface from another interface then you inherited the need to implement that interface as well.  Scary quotes around "derive", when you inherit something then you usually get richer, interface inheritance makes you poorer since it requires you to do more work.  You did that work, Unexpected really does implement ICommand since it implements Execute().

Comment: Thank you for the valuable (and entertaining) explanation, @HansPassant,  It's amazing that I have been at this for over a decade and yet the fundamentals continue to surprise me.  I was indeed able to add `void ICommand.Execute( object parameter ) {}` to my `Unexpected` class and it worked without exception, even though I have `ICommand.Execute` implemented on the base class, making two implementations of the same interface?  Yikes.  So, more for me to investigate/learn here, clearly.  If you please, submit this as an answer and I will accept it.